# Does this basic rerun function if error look ok

Tags: google-apps-script

My script works perfectly fine right now, I would like feedback on this basic function that I wrote in Google Apps Script.

What it does is if there is an unknown error in the try section I have the catch section check to see if the *runNumber* is equal to the *maxNumRetries* if yes then it ends the function else it will add 1 to the *runNumber* and rerun the function.

Is there any reason I shouldn't do this or is this an OK solution?

```
function runTest(run) {
  try{
    var runNumber = !run ? 0 : run;
    Logger.log('try number: ' + runNumber);
    throw '';
  }catch(e){
    var maxNumRetries = 3;
    if(runNumber == maxNumRetries){
      Logger.log('Max number reached');
    }else{
      runNumber = runNumber + 1;
      Logger.log('catch number ' + runNumber);
      runTest(runNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Totally fine (that is, ofc, if your function potentially recieves different inputs each run). I would suggest a couple small modification points: `var runNumber = run||0` and `runNumber++` as shortcuts + using strict comparison at all times (`runNumber===maxNumRetries`)

Comment: @OlegValter thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think you want `(runNumber >= maxNumRetries)`, or else you'll wind up exceeding the stack limit if you start with a number bigger than `maxNumRetries`.  Maybe that won't be possible with your input, but it wouldn't hurt.